# How to change the Keras sample code model.fit to generator manner?

Tags: keras, lstm

I'm trying to implement a CNN+RNN+LSTM structure(1) with Keras.

[image]

And I found a related Keras [sample code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5032).

How can I convert the model.fit to model.fit_generator correctly?

Original code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, LSTM, Flatten, Merge, TimeDistributed
import numpy as np

from keras.layers import Concatenate

from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D

# Generate fake data
# Assumed to be 1730 grayscale video frames
x_data = np.random.random((1730, 1, 8, 10))

sequence_lengths = None


Izda=Sequential()
Izda.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(40,(3,3),padding='same'), input_shape=(sequence_lengths, 1,8,10)))
Izda.add(Activation('relu'))
Izda.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(data_format="channels_first", pool_size=(2, 2))))
Izda.add(Dropout(0.2))

Dcha=Sequential()
Dcha.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(40,(3,3),padding='same'), input_shape=(sequence_lengths, 1,8,10)))
Dcha.add(Activation('relu'))
Dcha.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(data_format="channels_first", pool_size=(2, 2))))
Dcha.add(Dropout(0.2))

Frt=Sequential()
Frt.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(40,(3,3),padding='same'), input_shape=(sequence_lengths, 1,8,10)))
Frt.add(Activation('relu'))
Frt.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(data_format="channels_first", pool_size=(2, 2))))
Frt.add(Dropout(0.2))

merged=Merge([Izda, Dcha,Frt], mode='concat', concat_axis=2)
#merged=Concatenate()([Izda, Dcha, Frt], axis=2)
# Output from merge is (batch_size, sequence_length, 120, 4, 5)
# We want to get this down to (batch_size, sequence_length, 120*4*5)

model=Sequential()
model.add(merged)
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(240, return_sequences=True))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()
```

After my modification:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, LSTM, Flatten, Merge, TimeDistributed
import numpy as np

from keras.layers import Concatenate

from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D

# Generate fake data
# Assumed to be 1730 grayscale video frames
x_data = np.random.random((1730, 1, 8, 10))

sequence_lengths = None

def defModel():

    model=Sequential()
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(40,(3,3),padding='same'), input_shape=(sequence_lengths, 1,8,10)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(data_format="channels_first", pool_size=(2, 2))))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
    model.add(LSTM(240, return_sequences=True))

    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    model.summary()
    return model


def gen():
    for i in range(1730):
        x_train = np.random.random((1, 8, 10))
        y_train = np.ones((15, 240))
        yield (x_train, y_train)

def main():
    model = defModel()

    # Slice our long, single sequence up into shorter sequeunces of images
    # Let's make 50 examples of 15 frame videos
    x_train = []
    seq_len = 15
    for i in range(50):
        x_train.append(x_data[i*5:i*5+seq_len, :, :, :])
    x_train = np.asarray(x_train, dtype='float32')
    print(x_train.shape)
    # >> (50, 15, 1, 8, 10)

    model.fit_generator(
        generator = gen(),
        steps_per_epoch = 1,
        epochs = 2)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How can I resolve this error produce from by my modification?

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected
>   time_distributed_1_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with
>   shape (1, 8, 10)

(1) Wang, S., Clark, R., Wen, H., & Trigoni, N. (2017). DeepVO: Towards end-to-end visual odometry with deep Recurrent Convolutional Neural Networks. Proceedings - IEEE International Conference on Robotics and Automation, 2043–2050.

## Update: Concatenate CNN and LSTM as sample code

```
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, (7, 7),padding='same'),input_shape=(None, 540, 960, 1))) 
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (5, 5),padding='same'))) model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten())) 
model.add(LSTM(num_classes, return_sequences=True))
```

### Got error

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected lstm_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (4, 3)

## Update2

The goal is to extract image feature by CNN, then combine 3 feature from 3 images and feed into LSTM.

### Goal

```
#Input image
(540, 960, 1) ==> (x,y,ch) ==> CNN ==> (m,n,k)┐
(540, 960, 1) ==> (x,y,ch) ==> CNN ==> (m,n,k)---> (3, m,n,k) --flatten--> (3, mnk)
(540, 960, 1) ==> (x,y,ch) ==> CNN ==> (m,n,k)」

(3, mnk) => LSTM => predict three regression value
```

### Model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, (7, 7), padding='same'),input_shape=(None, 540, 960, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), padding='same')))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(num_classes, return_sequences=True))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

### The generator

```
a = readIMG(filenames[start])  # (540, 960, 1)
b = readIMG(filenames[start + 1])  # (540, 960, 1)
c = readIMG(filenames[start + 2])  # (540, 960, 1)
x_train = np.array([[a, b, c]])  # (1, 3, 540, 960, 1)
```

Then I still got the error:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected lstm_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a plain shape mismatch problem.

You defined `input_shape=(sequence_lengths, 1,8,10)`, so your model is expecting five dimensions as input: `(batch_size, sequence_lengths, 1, 8, 10)`

All you need is to make your generator output the correct shapes with 5 dimensions.

```
def gen():
    x_data = np.random.random((numberOfVideos, videoLength, 1, 8, 10))
    y_data = np.ones((numberOfVideos, videoLength, 240))

    for video in range(numberOfVideos):
        x_train = x_data[video:video+1]
        y_train = y_data[video:video+1]
        yield (x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: The solution above resolved the error! 
After modifying the sample code to DeepVO like structure, I got another error. (Detail in **Update** section of the original question.)  Doesn't the Flattern function output a vector that could match with LSTM?

Comment: That error is about "target" (the final output of the model). Your LSTM has `return_sequences=True`, so it outputs `(batch, length, output_features)`. But your data seems to have only `(batch, output_features)`. Either the data is wrong or you need to remove `return_sequences` to output only `(batch, features)`.

Comment: "**but got array with shape (4, 3)**" is out of my expectation.  Shouldn't the dimension of tensor after Flatten layer been squeeze to (n) ?  Why I still get (n,m) dimension?

Comment: That's `y_train`.

Comment: But you get `(batch, length, features)` after the flatten because it's time distributed. If it was alone, you would get `(batch, features)`.

Comment: You get `(batch, length, features)` after the LSTM because it has `return_sequences=True`. Otherwise you would get `(batch, features)`.

Comment: Thanks for explanations!!  One more question on how can I use the generator to produce (batch, length, features)?  Timedistributed CNN takes (540,960,1) image input in every convolusion iteration.  The output tensor of CNN will be flatten.  Where can I specify the "length" written in generator?

Comment: Detail in Update2

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example of CNNLSTM using generator: https://gist.github.com/HTLife/25c0cd362faa91477b8f28f6033adb45